# Forcing Laravel 5.7 to HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I need help forcing Laravel 5.7 on my site to use https.

I'm on a shared host, and this morning my hosting provider "upgraded" the server I'm on from cPanel to Site Tools. In the process, my custom Laravel app got broken.

My hosting provider hasn't provided much help, and I've been searching forums all day and trying lots of different things to no avail. I'm not very knowledgeable about Laravel, and some of the things I've seen on forums about this reference files that don't seem to exist in my particular Laravel app. (I didn't develop this app...definitely above my paygrade.) Some of the forums talk about clearing the cache, but I don't have access to the terminal on a shared host to clear the cache. I've tried making adjustments in .htaccess and .env, but I really don't know what I'm doing.

Currently in dev tools on Chrome I'm getting lots of "Mixed Content" errors. The CSS and JS resources are  trying to load http even though the site is https, and they're getting blocked.

Please help. I'll be glad to post code excerpts from my files upon request.

**Edit:**

I think part of my problem is that my Laravel app seems to be missing several of the default pieces that are included usually. For example, I don't have a "config" folder at all. But I don't know if grabbing that folder from a repository and simply adding that folder and the files therein to my app solves the problem.

**Edit:**

Here is my `AppServiceProvider` file from `app\Providers\`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
      if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
      }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this in the `AppServiceProvider` in the `boot()` method

```php
if(env('APP_ENV') === "production") {
   \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

it will force all your assets to `https` if you use laravel url helpers like `assts()` etc.

then if you want no one cannot access `http` version of your application

then you need to configure your server

you can add in `.htaccess`

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Kamlesh. I've added the lines to the `boot()` method in `AppServiceProvider`, and I have verified that the `APP_ENV` in my `.env` file is set to `production`. I've also added the lines you recommended to the `.htaccess` in Laravel `public` folder. Unfortunately, there was no change. Is there some kind of cache in Laravel that needs to clear, or should the changes be reflected immediately? (I have previously disabled caching at the server level.)

Comment: @maelstrom you need to create config

Comment: Can you give me more details about creating config? I know very little about Laravel.

Comment: @maelstrom you can read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: My site is on a shared host with no terminal access. I think I need access to the terminal to enter these commands, right? Also, I don't have a `config` folder. Is that because I am using Laravel 5.7?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.7/config laravel 5.7 config folder

Comment: Okay I've been able to get access to terminal via SSH. I've added in the contents of the `config` folder from the github repository. But when I try to run the `php artisan config:cache` command, I get `There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace`. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just change all your references on your template file from:

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

If you are using the Laravel asset() helper, you need to force the schema to https.  On the best case scenario, you should use CORS package, but a quick fix is to add the follwing to the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

public function boot() 
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's a good way to verify that the switch from http to https would fix the issue, but my CSS and JS references have these specific Laravel references like: `<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`, so I think I need to make some kind of Laravel config change to fix the issue site-wide.

Comment: Added the case when using helper functions

Comment: Thanks @JoeGalind. I had added those lines to my `AppServiceProvider` based on other forums I had visited, but it seems to have no effect. What else am I missing? Also, does it matter whether I put a backslash in front of `URL::forceScheme('https');` or not? Some of the forums show that, others do not.

Comment: Added the content of my `AppServiceProvider` above